# How i can add multiple data to the same token on firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this to add elements on my real time database:

```
mEditTextTitulo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTitulo);
    mEditTextMensaje = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDescripcion);
    mFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFecha);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    EnviarRTB = findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
    EnviarRTB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            String titulo = mEditTextTitulo.getText().toString();
            String descripcion = mEditTextMensaje.getText().toString();
            String fecha = mFecha.getText().toString();

            mDatabase.child("Eventos").push().child("Publicacion").child("Titulo").setValue(titulo);
            mDatabase.child("Eventos").push().child("Publicacion").child("Descripción").setValue(descripcion);
            mDatabase.child("Eventos").push().child("Publicacion").child("Fecha").setValue(fecha);
        }
    });
```

But this show my in the data base like this.

[image]

Must see like this

[image]

Comment: How would you like your database to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Generate key one time use it multiple times. You don't need to use push many time

```
EnviarRTB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        String key = mDatabase.child("Eventos").push().getKey();
        String titulo = mEditTextTitulo.getText().toString();
        String descripcion = mEditTextMensaje.getText().toString();
        String fecha = mFecha.getText().toString();

        mDatabase.child("Eventos").child(key).child("Publicacion").child("Titulo").setValue(titulo);
        mDatabase.child("Eventos").child(key).child("Publicacion").child("Descripción").setValue(descripcion);
        mDatabase.child("Eventos").child(key).child("Publicacion").child("Fecha").setValue(fecha);
    }
});
```